# Actualizar el valor de una variable global tras evento click - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hola necesito actualizar y poder trabajar con el valor actualizado de una variable global despues de ser actualizada tras un evento click.
En la variable "resultado" necesito obtener el valor actualizado de la variable aux.

Expongo mi ejemplo:

```
var aux = '0';

$(document).on('click', '.edit',   function pruebas(){
                                            
    id=$(this).val();   //Recojo el valor del id de la fila seleccionada
                                
    

    aux = id;

    

    return aux; //Este valor si que está actualizado
                                        
});

resultado = aux; //Me devuelve el valor inicial ('0') y no el actualizado en la función tras el evento
```

Comment: Aún no se ha hecho clic en el elemento, por eso no cambia el valor. Sería bueno ver en qué contexto lo planeas usar para poder sugerirte algo. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega más información.

Comment: Saludos. ¿Así tal cual muestras el código lo checas?. El valor de la variable cambia hasta hacer cliquear en el componente  y desde luego que este no tenga el mismo que asignas inicialmente a aux para que veas el cambio.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es recoger el valor del id que se obtiene al hacer el click, y sacarlo fuera de la función, para poder trabajar posteriormente con ese nuevo valor

Comment: @CristianMilani un evento oyente no debe ser usado para ese proposito, para eso debes usar funciones normales, la sentencia `return` simplemente no tiene sentido usarla dentro de un evento oyente, en tu caso un `onclick`, lo que tienes que hacer es en vez de intentar colocar `resultado = aux;` afuera, lo debes colocar dentro del cuerpo del evento, para que me entiendas mejor, el evento no se ejecuta si no hasta que hagas click, pero el flujo del programa sigue, por lo tanto de inicios `aux` vale `0`, por lo cual en ese instante a `resultado` tambien se le estara asignando `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso no hay necesidad de hacerte líos con `return`, además, si trabajas con `return` el modo de hacerlo sería asignando a una variable el resultado de la función que haría el `return`.

Dicho eso, si declaras `aux` en el ámbito global, luego basta con asignar un valor a `aux` en cualquier otro ámbito y listo.

Veamos un ejemplo de tres botones. Aquí declaramos `aux` como lo tienes inicialmente. Luego, dentro del listener de los botones 1 y 3 `aux` adquirirá el valor del botón que sea presionado y cuando pulsas en el botón 2, verás cualquiera de los dos valores que `aux` haya adquirido según el botón presionado. Es sólo a modo de ejemplo para mostrar que el valor de `aux` cambiará sin que haga falta retornar nada desde dentro de la función de escucha.

```js
var aux = '0';
$(".edit").on('click', function() {
  aux = $(this).val();
  $("#btnTwo").prop('disabled', false);
  console.log("Ahora haz clic en Paso 2");
});

$("#btnTwo").on('click', function() {
  console.log(`El último botón que presionaste fue ${aux}  y la variable aux tiene ese valor`);
  $("#btnTwo").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="edit" value="btnOne">Paso 1A (click aquí)</button>
<hr />
<button id="btnTwo" value="btnTwo" disabled>Paso 2 (click aquí)</button>
<hr />
<button class="edit" value="btnThree">Paso 1B (click aquí)</button>
```

### Nota sobre optimización y estandarización del código

> En el código he implementado un modo de escucha más claro según el
> estándar de jQuery. Ten en cuenta que las llamadas que usan `document`
> están siendo abandonadas por jQuery (muchas de ellas han sido
> declaradas obsoletas), por eso te aconsejo que evites el uso de
> `document` cuando trabajes con jQuery, es, por decirlo de alguna
> forma, una sintaxis más propia de versiones antiguas de jQuery y parte
> de esa sintaxis (si no toda) dejará de funcionar en jQuery 4.